# How to import a .proto file in Matlab

Tags: matlab, protocol-buffers

I've downloaded and installed protobuf-matlab from [farsounder](https://github.com/farsounder/protobuf-matlab) and am struggling to understand how to use this to import a *.proto file into Matlab. 
So far, I've used the `protoc --matlab_out` option compilor which creates Matlab m files of the form `pb_descriptor_*` and `pb_read_*` to create and read the fields in the protobuf file.

How does one actually practically accomplish reading a .proto file? In the help the input is a buffer (a buffer of unint8's to parse). In Matlab, how do I create such a buffer in order to use the pb_read_* functions to import the relevant fields?

Answer (score 0):

I think

```
fid = fopen(filename);
buf = fread(fid, [1 inf], '*uint8');
fclose(fid);
message = pb_read_proto__<your_message_name>(buf);
```

is what you're looking for.